# How To Strip Hebrew Accent Marks

Tags: sql-server, collation, encoding, unicode

I need a Char Encoding Trick to Strip Hebrew Accent Marks.

**Sample Before**

> בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית בָּרָ֣א אֱלֹהִ֑ים אֵ֥ת הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם וְאֵ֥ת הָאָֽרֶץ

**Sample After**

> בראשית ברא אלהים את השמים ואת הארץ

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The trick here is to realize that these characters that you see in the question with the "accents" aren't really *the* characters (i.e. "These aren't the <del>droids</del>characters you are looking for" ;-) ). The "accents" are various types of notations indicating things like:

- vowels (lines and dots that are typically under the letters):

  ## base letter "ה" = "h"; "הֶ" = "heh" and "הָ" = "hah"
- pronunciation (dots that are usually inside or above letters):

  ## "בּ" = "b" vs "ב" = "v", or "שׂ" = "s" vs "שׁ" = "sh"
- punctuation
- cantillation (how it should be sung)

The actual Hebrew letters are what is shown in the stripped down version (i.e. the end result of what is being requested here). What we are referring to here as "accents" are known as diacritical marks. The Wikipedia article on [Hebrew diacritics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_diacritics) has a lot of good information about these marks, including the following image and caption:

[image: Gen. 1:9 And God said, "Let the waters be collected"]

<sup>Gen. 1:9 And God said, "Let the waters be collected".
Letters in black, pointing in red, cantillation in blue</sup>

Getting from those base characters to what the first line (with the vowels, etc) shows is a matter of adding one or more "accents". Unicode (UTF-16 in SQL Server, though default interpretation only handles the UCS-2 / Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP) code points) allows for some characters to overlay another non-overlay character when adjacent to them. These are known as [Combining Characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character).

Meaning:

```sql
SELECT DATALENGTH(N'מַ֖'); -- character taken from original given text
```

Returns:

```
6
```

not `2` as most people would expect from seeing a single, double-byte character. So maybe we try to find what character is there by doing:

```sql
SELECT UNICODE(N'מַ֖');
```

which returns:

```
1502
```

Of course, the `UNICODE` and `ASCII` functions only return the `INT` value of the first character of whatever string they are given. But a value of 1502 only covers 2 bytes, which leaves 4 bytes unaccounted for. Looking at the binary/hex values of that same Hebrew "character":

```sql
SELECT NCHAR(1502), CONVERT(BINARY(2), UNICODE(N'מַ֖')), CONVERT(VARBINARY(10), N'מַ֖');
```

we get:

```
מ
0x05DE  0xDE05B7059605
```

Now, **0x05DE** is the hex representation of 1502, and the 1502 is only the "**מ**". The next part can be separated into three 2-byte sets: **DE05** **B705** **9605**. Now, Unicode string values are stored in Little Endian, which means the byte-order is reversed. If we switch each of those three sets we get:

**05DE** (the base character) **05B7** **0596** (the unaccounted for 4 bytes).

Ok. So what happens if we remove that base character?

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(N'מַ֖' COLLATE Hebrew_BIN2, NCHAR(1502) COLLATE Hebrew_BIN2, '');
```

That returns the two remaining characters (not easy to see here so I have made the following line a header in order to increase the font size; you can also run the above `REPLACE` to see them):

## Removing the מ from the מַ֖ leaves two characters at the bottom: ַ֖

Hence, we need to strip out each individual code-point that is one of these "extra" combining characters (found at: http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=hebrew) and that will leave us with the base characters. We can do that via:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RemoveHebrewAccents (@txeTwerbeH NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN

  WITH base (dummy) AS
  (
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
  ), nums AS
  (
    -- we will want to generate code points 1425 - 1479
    SELECT TOP (55) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS [Num]
    FROM   base b1
    CROSS JOIN base b2
  )
  SELECT @txeTwerbeH = REPLACE(
                               @txeTwerbeH COLLATE Hebrew_BIN2,
                               NCHAR(1424 + nums.[Num]) COLLATE Hebrew_BIN2,
                               ''
                              )
  FROM   nums;

  RETURN @txeTwerbeH;
END;
```

And then we can test it with the original text as follows:

```sql
DECLARE @Hebrew NVARCHAR(200) = N'בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית בָּרָ֣א אֱלֹהִ֑ים אֵ֥ת הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם וְאֵ֥ת הָאָֽרֶץ';

SELECT dbo.RemoveHebrewAccents(@Hebrew);
```

Returns:

## בראשית ברא אלהים את השמים ואת הארץ

---

Additional notes:

- Technically, there is a set of code-points between 64298 and 64334 that do have *some* vowels and pronunciation "accents" built into the character. If those need to be handled, that can be a second step in the function to do a simple replacement of those characters.
- It seems that these accent, punctuation, etc code-points only match when using a binary collation. Even using `Hebrew_100_CS_AS_KS_WS_SC` did not match them. But the following did work: `Hebrew_BIN`, `Hebrew_BIN2`, `Latin1_General_BIN`, and `Latin1_General_BIN2`. In the function I ended up using `Hebrew_BIN2`. Please note that when using binary collations, unless you have a specific need to use the older `_BIN` collations, you should only be using the newer `_BIN2` collations.
- For anyone who is curious, the Hebrew sample text is actually Bereishis 1:1 (that is also the first word on the right-side as Hebrew is read right-to-left; in English it would be "Genesis 1:1" though that is not a direct translation of the word, just the name of the first book of the Torah / Bible; the direct translation is "in the beginning"):

  > In the beginning of God's creating the heavens and the Earth
- **2015-01-19:** I found some great resources which explain both Combining Characters and the Hebrew character set:

  - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character (also linked towards the top of this answer)
  - http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/combining_diacritical_marks.html
  - http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/hebrew.html
  - http://people.w3.org/rishida/scripts/pickers/hebrew/  (play with all of the characters in the Hebrew character set; very cool!)

Comment: @Kin Thanks! (again :). Let's see how long your comment survives this time ;-D   (note to our ghost cleanup "process": that was not meant to have any rude or snide implications, and this smiley with halo proves that   as does this smiling cat    )

Comment: and again I learn something unexpected from your answers.  Nice!

Comment: Wow!  A nice linguistics answer thrown in with an *excellent* description of handling encoding!  Thanks, Solomon!

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting problem, and one I sort of faced a while back working with Japanese characters. I hit a bit of a brick wall trying to locate your problem characters, though I hope this gets you going somewhere with finding them.

First I got all NCHARs into a table:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON  

DECLARE @cnt INT = 1
DECLARE @sqlcmd NVARCHAR(512) = ''

CREATE TABLE #CHARS (
[CharOrder] INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
[Result] NVARCHAR(4) 
)

WHILE @cnt < 65536
BEGIN

SELECT @sqlcmd = '
INSERT #CHARS
    ([Result] )
SELECT NCHAR(' + CAST(@cnt AS NVARCHAR) + ')
'

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sqlcmd

SET @cnt +=1 
END
```

Then I located one of the non-accented chars:

```
SELECT  c.CharOrder, c.Result
FROM    #CHARS AS c
WHERE c.Result = N'ר'
ORDER BY c.CharOrder
```

Then I located the range of chars that Hebrew characters are in:

```
SELECT  c.CharOrder, c.Result
FROM    #CHARS AS c
WHERE c.CharOrder >= 1488
AND c.CharOrder < 1523
ORDER BY c.CharOrder
```

But trying to find the accented chars you want, they don't seem to show up, except one hit at code 8501.

```
SELECT  c.CharOrder ,
        c.Result
FROM    #CHARS AS c
WHERE   c.Result IN ( N'רֵ', N'א', N'שִׁ֖', N'י', N'ת', N'בְּ', N'בָּ', N'רָ֣',
                      N'א', N'אֱ', N'לֹ', N'הִ֑', N'י', N'ם', N'אֵ֥', N'ת',
                      N'הַ', N'שָּׁ', N'מַ֖', N'יִ', N'ם', N'וְ', N'אֵ֥', N'ת',
                      N'הָ', N'אָֽ', N'רֶ', N'ץ' )
ORDER BY c.CharOrder
```

So just looking at the surrounding characters, I can't really identify any other matches to your text.

```
SELECT  c.CharOrder, c.Result
FROM    #CHARS AS c
WHERE c.CharOrder >= 8499
AND c.CharOrder < 8539
ORDER BY c.CharOrder
```

A lot of them seem to get thrown as those nebulous little rectangles of whatever.

Again, sorry it's not a solution, but hope it helps.

Comment: re: "trying to find the accented chars you want, they don't seem to show up", that's because they don't exist ;-). I explain in more detail in my answer, but basically it is a base character with one or two overlay characters that take up the same visible position as the base character.

Comment: That's really cool. I never would have thought that those marks were separate from the characters. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a Numbers table.  There are any number of posts explaining what this is, why its useful and how to get one efficiently.

I don't use any built-in functionality to convert accented characters to the non-accented equivalent.  Instead I build a lookup list which you will populate with the conversions you require.  You will have to use `nvarchar` and define your translations as `N'x'`, of course.

Thanks to [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f09d4166-2030-41fe-b86e-392fbc94db53/tsql-equivalent-for-groupconcat-function?forum=transactsql) for the row concatenation tip.

```
drop table #Numbers;

select
    *
into #Numbers
from 
    (
    select *
    from (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11)) as T(N)
    ) as xx;

drop table #Lookups;

select
    *
into #Lookups
from 
    (
    select *
    from (values ('a','m'),('b','n'),('c','o'),('d','p'),('e','q'),('m','z')) as T(CharFrom,CharTo)
    ) as xx;


drop table #Inputs;

select
    *
into #Inputs
from 
    (
    select *
    from (values ('abcdefghi')
                ,('abtcd')
        ) as T(Word)
    ) as xx;


select
     ix.Word as Original
    ,(
    select
        Coalesce(l.CharTo, SUBSTRING(i.word, n.N, 1)) -- do not alias
    from #Inputs as i
    cross apply #Numbers as n
    left join #Lookups as l
        on l.CharFrom = SUBSTRING(i.word, n.N, 1)
    where n.N <= LEN(i.Word)
    and i.Word = ix.Word
    for xml path ('')
    ) as Substituted
from #Inputs as ix;
```

Comment: Michael, Hebrew doesn't actually work that way. These aren't truly "accented characters" in the same way that these are: `Ü ö ò ô å Ä Å É ï`. Hence, a standard translation/mapping method won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked if anyone in the future wants.

`function accentHebrewToCleanHebrew($accentHebrew){
    //Strip Extras
    $search = array("&#1425;", "&#1426;", "&#1427;", "&#1428;", "&#1429;",
    "&#1430;", "&#1431;", "&#1432;", "&#1433;", "&#1434;", "&#1435;", "&#1436;",
    "&#1437;", "&#1438;", "&#1439;", "&#1440;", "&#1441;", "&#1442;", "&#1443;",
    "&#1444;", "&#1445;", "&#1446;", "&#1447;", "&#1448;", "&#1449;", "&#1450;",
    "&#1451;", "&#1452;", "&#1453;", "&#1454;", "&#1455;", "&#1456;", "&#1457;",
    "&#1458;", "&#1459;", "&#1460;", "&#1461;", "&#1462;", "&#1463;", "&#1464;",
    "&#1465;", "&#1466;", "&#1467;", "&#1468;", "&#1469;", "&#1470;", "&#1471;",
    "&#1472;", "&#1473;", "&#1474;", "&#1475;", "&#1476;", "&#1477;", "&#1478;", "&#1479;");
    $replace = "";
    $cleanHebrew = str_replace($search, $replace, $accentHebrew);
    return $cleanHebrew;
}`