# Encoding issue with SQL Server VARCHAR column retrieved in Python

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, python, encoding, utf-8

We recently had an issue with encoding related to a field that's being stored as a varchar(120) in SQL Server.  In SSMS, the varchar appears as:

"Who Killed JonBen‚t?"

However, when it's brought into python, it appears as:

[image]

I've researched this from the Python side, and nothing strange is going on.  My theory is that the varchar in SQL Server is accepting UTF-8 characters which are displaying differently in python than SSMS.  I'm not very familiar with encoding in SQL Server.  Can someone please let me know the following:

- Is there a way in SSMS to view the encoding of the varchar?  For instance see \x82 instead of displaying the comma as it is currently from SSMS?
- We're using SQL Server 2008.  Is there any way to change the encoding for any UTF-8 characters to ASCII characters without using import /export tools or dumping to a flat file?  I.e. can I make this conversion via a query?
- Is there any way to programmatically identify problematic records via a query (problematic being defined as UTF-8 characters that are not supported via ASCII)?

Thank you in advance!

Using `sp_help N'table_name';` I found that the Collation of this `VARCHAR` column is: `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

Comment: What Collation is that `VARCHAR` column using?

Comment: @SolomonRutzky how do you check the collation. I'm not sure what that even means

Comment: The quickest way I think is: `sp_help N'table_name';`. Look at the column based on "name" and then look at the "collation_name" column.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky the collation for that field is 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'

Answer (score 24, accepted):

SQL Server does not store UTF-8 under any circumstances. You get either UTF-16 Little Endian (LE) via `NVARCHAR` (including `NCHAR` and `NTEXT`, but don't ever use `NTEXT`) and `XML`, or some 8-bit encoding, based on a Code Page, via `VARCHAR` (including `CHAR` and `TEXT`, but don't ever use `TEXT`).

The problem here is that your code is mistranslating that 0x82 character, thinking that it's UTF-8, but it's not. There is no UTF-8 "character" having a value of 0x82, which is why you get the "unknown" / replacement symbol of "�". Please see the following UTF-8 table which shows that there is no character for a single-byte of 0x82:

[UTF-8 encoding table](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/)

As stated by the O.P., the Collation of the column in question is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`, which means that the 8-bit encoding is using Code Page 1252, which is [Windows Latin 1 (ANSI)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195054.aspx). And checking that chart (scroll down to the bottom chart as it has the character names) value 0x82 (look for "82" in the "Code Point" column) is in fact the [Single Low-9 Quotation Mark](https://unicode-table.com/en/201A/) that you see in SSMS. That character, in UTF-8, is a 3 byte sequence: `E2 80 9A`.

What all of this means is: your Python code needs to either set the client-encoding for the SQL Server connection to Code Page 1252, or you need to change / convert the encoding of the returned string *from* Code Page 1252 *to* UTF-8.

Of course, if this is being displayed on a web page, then you *could* change the declared charset of the page to be `Windows-1252`, but that might interfere with other characters on the page if there are UTF-8 characters already there.

Comment: Nice, this is very helpful, thank you Solomon.  Please do let me know about the mistranslation.  This is a pretty tricky issue and I'm not even sure where to start with it.

Comment: Wow, amazing detail, @Solomon ! I landed here looking for a different Python + MS SQL problem, but kept reading because I was learning so much.  :-P

Comment: @MikeWilliamson Thanks for sharing that compliment :). You might also be interested in the following: [TSQL md5 hash different to C# .NET md5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27912130/577765) (on S.O.), [How To Strip Hebrew Accent Marks](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/84266/30859) (here on DBA.SE), and [Collations.Info](https://collations.info/). Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks!  I suspect anyone working with a non-Latin-based language knows this stuff **far** better than any of us blissfully working in the US/UK.  :)

Comment: Just a note: MS SQL Server 2019 introduces native support for UTF-8 in VARCHAR / CHAR datatypes.